# GRPC error: 14 UNAVAILABLE: No connection established

Tags: nestjs, grpc

I am developing a microservices project using **NestJS** and **gRPC**.
When I run my project locally it runs successfully, however when the project is uploaded to docker I get the error message "**Error: 14 UNAVAILABLE: No connection established**".

This is the docker-compose file that I wrote.

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  gateway-service:
    container_name: gateway-service
    restart: always
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: './apps/gateway-service/Dockerfile'
    volumes:
      - .:/app
      - /app/node_modules
    env_file:
      - .env
    environment:
      - MONGODB_HOST=mongodb://mongodb:27017/
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    command: npm run start:dev gateway-service
    networks:
      - sgod_network
    depends_on:
      - mongodb
  user-service:
    container_name: user-service
    restart: always
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: './apps/user-service/Dockerfile'
    volumes:
      - .:/app
      - /app/node_modules
    env_file:
      - .env
    environment:
      - MONGODB_HOST=mongodb://mongodb:27017/
    command: npm run start:dev user-service
    networks:
      - sgod_network
    depends_on:
      - mongodb
  mongodb:
    image: mongo
    ports:
      - 27018:27017
    networks:
      - sgod_network

networks:
  sgod_network:
    driver: bridge
```

Here I have registered gRPC.

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    ClientsModule.register([
      {
        name: USER_PACKAGE_NAME,
        transport: Transport.GRPC,
        options: {
          package: USER_PACKAGE_NAME,
          protoPath: join(__dirname, '.././user.proto'),
          url: '127.0.0.1:50001',
        },
      },
    ]),
  ],
  controllers: [GatewayServiceController],
  providers: [GatewayServiceService],
})
```

In user-service I have also configured gRPC

```
const app = await NestFactory.createMicroservice<MicroserviceOptions>(
    UserServiceModule,
    {
      transport: Transport.GRPC,
      options: {
        package: USER_PACKAGE_NAME,
        protoPath: join(__dirname, '.././user.proto'),
        url: '127.0.0.1:50001',
      },
    },
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you have two approaches to solve this.

- Firstly, you can map the port outside the host using Docker's host network.
- Secondly, you can change the URL from 127.0.0.1 to the container's name. For example, based on your docker-compose, the url will be user-service:50001.

For more details, you should explore Docker's two network types: host and bridge.

Comment: Thank you so much. Your instructions helped me solve the problem.